# Oddly placed CSS

Tags: html, css

I want my news content to be completely centered (including image and text), but instead, it's oddly placed to the right like this:
http://prntscr.com/3o7tjc

I tried most ways to fix it and I can't find it... um...
Here is the HTML part:

```
<div id="mainContentContainer">
    <div id="mainContent">

        <div class="postTitle">
            test
        </div>
        <div class="posterInfo">
            <img width="40%" class="profilePic" src="/site/uploads/avatars/f3780c97491dd9f62f0dd7b1b8bb090a0b9e87d0.png">
            <p>Posted by: <a class="postedBy" href="#">test</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="postContent">
            <div class="postImageContainer" align="center">
                <img class="postImage" src="../uploads/img/test">
            </div>

            <div class="post">
                <p>test</p>
            </div>
            Comments have been disabled for this post.</div>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            Welcome, Admin<br><a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Annnd, here is the CSS.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #6C9DDF;
    background-image:url("/assets/img/background.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.hq {
    position:relative;
    top:40px;
    width:1300px;
    height:100%;
    left:1%;
}
#logo {
    position:absolute;
    width:40%;
    height:30%;
    right:30%;
    z-index: 100;
}
#homebtn, #playbtn, #newsbtn, #helpbtn {
    background: url(/assets/img/menubtns.png) no-repeat;
}
#homebtn {
    background-image: url("/assets/img/home.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 75%;
    width: 204px;
    height: 184px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 318px;
    left: 353px;
}
#homebtn:hover {
    background-image: url("/assets/img/home-rollover.png");
}
#playbtn {
    background-image: url("/assets/img/play.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    height: 230px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 240px;
    left: 480px;
}
#playbtn:hover {
    background-image: url("/assets/img/play-rollover.png");
}
#newsbtn {
    background-image: url("/assets/img/news.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 290px;
    height: 290px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 210px;
    left: 650px;
}
#newsbtn:hover {
    background-image: url("/assets/img/news-rollover.png");
}
#helpbtn {
    background-image: url("/assets/img/help.png");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 330px;
    height: 380px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 930px;
}
#helpbtn:hover {
    background-image: url("/assets/img/help-rollover.png");
}

#mainContentContainer {
    border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    border: 8px solid #000000;
    background-color: #FFE12F;
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    top: 60px;
    left: 8%;
    padding: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%; 
  position: relative
}
#mainContent {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 900px;
}
#sidebar {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
.postTitle {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #515151;
    text-align: center;
}

.text {
    text-align: center;
}
.title {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #515151;
}
.title:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #515151;
}
.title:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.postedBy {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.posterInfo {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
.postContent {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.postImageContainer {
    padding: 5px;
}
.postImage {
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}
.profilePic {
    border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
}
.registerFormWrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.commentFormContainer {
    margin-top: 45px;
}
.commentContent {
    border-radius: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
    resize: none;
    padding: 10px;
    outline: none;
}
.commentBTN {
    background: url("../img/comment.png");
    width: 269px;
    height: 260px;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-indent: -999px;
}
.commentBTN:hover {
    background: url("../img/commentHover.png");
}
.ToonName {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.ToonNameInput {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    outline: none;
}
.commentBTNS {
    outline: none;
}
.commentFormInputContainer {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
}
.registerInput {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    outline: none;
}
.loginInput {
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 5px;
    outline: none;
}
.inputLabel {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I tried changing most possible combinations, and it didnt work exactly...

Here is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/2EYYC/

:EDIT:
Alright, I did use the thing I got told to and it did work but it appears I'm stuck with some kind of bar blocking the view.

Comment: A fiddle would help here....

Comment: ...as would a wide-screen monitor. Please sort out your tabbing.

Comment: oddly, it works on fiddle but on my site, it doesnt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the understand of the OP, here is a solution. I added `width` in pixels for the css class `profilePic`

```
.profilePic {
    border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    width: 120px; /* Width added here */
}
```

**Reason I added** - Since you mentioned the `width` as 40% and there was no defined width for the parent it was not able to take width properly. Changing the `width` to pixels does the trick.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/2EYYC/1/)**